# how does the UIView 's systemLayoutSizeFitting method works?

Tags: ios, uiview

In the documentation:

> Returns the size of the view that satisfies the constraints it holds.

OK, I create a view in storyboard, and add constraints:

```
yellowview.leading = self.view.leading

yellow view.trailing = self.view.trailing

yellow view.bottom = self.view.bottom

yelloview.height = 128
```

[image]

Now I print the `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize`, which I expect to be the `UIScreen` width and 128 height. but the result is:

```
====UILayoutFittingCompressedSize==
(0.0, 128.0)
====UILayoutFittingExpandedSize==
(10000.0, 128.0)
```

======================================

Then I create a view and add constrain for it through code:

```
    let btn :UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton(type: .Custom)
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return btn
    }()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addSubview(btn)
    btn.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 100).active = true
    btn.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -100).active = true
    btn.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.topAnchor, constant: 100).active = true
    btn.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -100).active = true
}
```

It shows nicely:

[image]

Now print it's `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize`:

```
=====UILayoutFittingExpandedSize==
(30.0, 34.0)
===UILayoutFittingCompressedSize==
(30.0, 34.0)
```

Which I expect to be `UIScreen` size: 100.

Why do I get these strange values? Or am I misunderstand the document?